# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Fails Every Time

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-hosted-agent

Currently, trying to configure a release pipeline in Azure Devops. I've successfully created a CI pipeline that is working and running tests successfully. My release pipeline uses the artifacts from latest the CI build and should be deploying to azure. When I look at the logs I can see the the following were completed successfully:

- Initialize Agent
- Initialize job
- Download arifact

and then the "Deploy to Azure App Service" fails with the logs showing the following details:

```
2019-02-07T19:06:57.5433805Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'MyApp'
2019-02-07T19:06:57.5487495Z ##[error]Error: Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name 'MyAPP'. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request
2019-02-07T19:06:57.5496340Z Failed to add release annotation. TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApplicationSettings' of undefined
```

I haven't been able to find much to help with this so far. I created the release pipeline by selecting `Azure App Service deployment` from the templates for stage 1 of the pipline (I only have one stage) and I added an artifact who's source is from my build pipeline. I then selected the Tasks tab and selected my Pay-as-you-go subscription under "Available Azure Service Connections". After selecting my subscription, my app service name became available in the "App service name" dropdown and I selected it. I then hit save and tried to create a release but every release fails with the above error message.

What can I do to overcome this?

Comment: mhm. are you using a hosted agent?

Comment: The Agent Pool that I have selected is Hosted VS2017

Comment: i'd open a support ticket in this case ;) not much you can do, try hosted ubuntu

Comment: @4c74356b41 finally found the answer to my issue if you're interested at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my issue. The problem was in the way I set up my service connection. I went to:

project settings -> service connections -> new service connection -> selected azure resource manager -> selected service principal authentication INSTEAD OF managed identity authentication -> a popup came up that allowed me to log in and authorize.

Then I used that service connection when creating the release pipeline instead of the pre-existing Pay-As-You-Go subscription that I used last time.

Previously when I tried this, I had an adblocker running and it blocked the popup which allowed me to authorize when I selected service principal authentication. That resulted in an "Unable to authorize account" error message which is why I went with managed identity authentication in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was related to a chrome extension I have added 'enable CORS' plugin. After disabling, release pipeline worked nicely