# Error: Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am in the process of creating a release pipeline for a node application to a web app in app services. The issue is i am getting this error :

> Error: Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name 'SurveySaysStaging'. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request.

I have activated MSI but it is still not working. I also could not find anything related to service principals in my settings and only shows details of the subscriptions. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was fixed, all i needed to do was create a service connection to the service group.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites'

According to the error message:

```
 Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name 'SurveySaysStaging'. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal.
```

If you are trying to run your release with the hosted agent, you may have this issue. Because A hosted agent doesn't support MSI based authentication.

In order to use MSI based Authentication, you need to configure a **private agent** on Azure VM and configure MSI on the Azure VM.

You could check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm#enable-system-assigned-identity-on-an-existing-vm) for some more details.

Note: You could verify if MSI based authentication has been configured properly please run below script from your PS on Azure VM:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://management.azure.com/" -Headers @{Metadata="true"} -Method Get
```

Besides, if you are already in private agent with activated MSI, you could check t[his thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581088/azure-devops-release-pipeline-fails-every-time) or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697192/azure-devops-unable-to-deploy-to-azure-web-app) for some helps.

Hope this helps.